# Magento 2 Error

Tags: magento2, controllers, magento2.2.6

can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong with this code

```
<?php

namespace Feedback\Addon\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Feedback\Addon\Model\InsertFactory;



class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Test
     */
    protected $_test;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
        InsertFactory $test
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_test = $test;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $test = $this->_test->create();

        $data=array(
                        'first_name'=> $post['first_name'],
                        'last_name'=> $post['last_name'],
                        'email' => $post['email'],
                        'mobile_no' => $post['mobile_no'],
                        'feedback_content' => $post['feedback_content']
                    );    

         $test->setData($data);

        if($test->save())
        {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the data.'));
            $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            $templateVars = array(
                                'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
                                'customer_name' => 'John Doe',
                                'message'   => 'Hello!!.'
                            );
            $from = array('email' => "test@example.com", 'name' => 'Name of Sender');
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $to = array('abc@example.com');

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $templateId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue ( 'feedback/custom/email_template', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId );

            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId, $storeScope)->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                        ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                        ->setFrom($from)
                        ->addTo($to)
                        ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Mail Sent Successfully'));
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

        }
        else
        {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Data was not saved.'));
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

I am trying to sending mail to the user after saving data but this is generated this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Feedback\Addon\Controller\Index\Save\Interceptor::__construct() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/nuluv/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111 and defined in /var/www/html/nuluv/generated/code/Feedback/Addon/Controller/Index/Save/Interceptor.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/nuluv/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Feedback\Addon\Controller\Index\Save\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context), Object(Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager), NULL, Object(Feedback\Addon\Model\InsertFactory)) #1 /var/www/html/nuluv/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Feedback\Addon\...', Array) #2 /var/www/html/nuluv/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Feedback\Addon\...', in /var/www/html/nuluv/generated/code/Feedback/Addon/Controller/Index/Save/Interceptor.php on line 11

Comment: Try to run following command & then check :
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:di:c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your constructor receive the mandatory parameters before the optional ones:

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
    InsertFactory $test,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_test = $test;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

and clear the contents of folder `generated/code`.

Comment: hi thanks for the help! I tired your code buy its generated error - Extra parameters passed to parent construct: $data. File: /var/www/html/nuluv/app/code/Feedback/Addon/Controller/Index/Save.php
Total Errors Count: 1

Comment: then remove $data from parent::__construct($context, $data);